# Trying to distort audio in Java

Tags: java, audio, filter, vst, distortion

I found a library called JVST that can load VST files and filter the audio accordingly. The problem is, I have no clue how to use it. All I could do is copy and paste the example code from the website and adapt it to my needs, yet it still doesn't work. What I'm trying to do is distort the audio from a .au or .wav file that the user selects to simulate a boombox. I'm not sure if multi-band compression is the best thing to use, but I'm going to try it, and if it fails, I have a load of custom VST plugins at my disposal. Anyways, here's the code:

```
import sun.audio.*; //import the sun.audio package
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.*;
import org.boris.jvst.*;
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class SoundPlayer extends Frame implements FilenameFilter {
Button openButton = new Button("Open");  
Button playButton = new Button("Play");
Button loopButton = new Button("Loop");
Button stopButton = new Button("Stop");
Label filename = new Label("                   ");
File theFile = null;
@SuppressWarnings({ "restriction" })
AudioData theData = null;
InputStream nowPlaying = null;

@SuppressWarnings({ "deprecation" })
public SoundPlayer() {
    super("Boombox");
    resize(300, 200);
    Panel north = new Panel();
    north.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
    north.add(new Label("File: "));
    north.add("North", filename);
    add("North", north);
    Panel south = new Panel();
    south.add(openButton);
    south.add(playButton);
    south.add(loopButton);
    south.add(stopButton);
    add("South", south);
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SoundPlayer sp = new SoundPlayer();
    sp.show();
}

@SuppressWarnings({ "deprecation", "restriction" })
public void open() {
    FileDialog fd = new FileDialog(this, "Please select a .au or .wav file:");
    fd.setFilenameFilter(this);
    fd.show();
    try {
        theFile = new File(fd.getDirectory() + "/" + fd.getFile());
        if (theFile != null) {
            filename.setText(theFile.getName());
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(theFile);
            AudioStream as = new AudioStream(fis);
            theData = as.getData();
        }
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println(e);
    }
}

@SuppressWarnings("restriction")
public void play() {
    stop();    
    if (theData == null) open();
    if (theData != null) {
        AudioDataStream ads = new AudioDataStream(theData);
        AudioPlayer.player.start(ads);
        nowPlaying = ads;
    }
}

@SuppressWarnings("restriction")
public void stop() {
    if (nowPlaying != null) {
        AudioPlayer.player.stop(nowPlaying);
        nowPlaying = null;
    }
}

@SuppressWarnings("restriction")
public void loop() {
    stop();
    if (theData == null) open();
    if (theData != null) {
        ContinuousAudioDataStream cads = new ContinuousAudioDataStream(theData);
        AudioPlayer.player.start(cads);
        nowPlaying = cads;
    }
}

public boolean action(Event e, Object what) {

    if (e.target == playButton) {
        play();
        return true;
    }
    else if (e.target == openButton) {
        open();
        return true;
    }
    else if (e.target == loopButton) {
        loop();
        return true;
    }
    else if (e.target == stopButton) {
        stop();
        return true;
    }

    return false;

}

public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {

    name = name.toLowerCase();
    if (name.endsWith(".au")) return true;
    if (name.endsWith(".wav")) return true;
    return false;
    public static void main(String[] args); throws Exception {
        AEffect a = VST.load("C:/Program Files (x86)/Audacity 1.3 Beta (Unicode)/Plug-Ins/mda MultiBand.dll");
        a.open();
        a.setSampleRate(44100.0f);
        a.setBlockSize(512);

        // attempt some processing
        int blocksize = 512;
        float[][] inputs = new float[a.numInputs][];
        for (int i = 0; i < a.numInputs; i++) {
            inputs[i] = new float[blocksize];
            for (int j = 0; j < blocksize; j++)
                inputs[i][j] = (float) Math
                .sin(j * Math.PI * 2 * 440 / 44100.0);
        }
        float[][] outputs = new float[a.numOutputs][];
        for (int i = 0; i < a.numOutputs; i++) {
            outputs[i] = new float[blocksize];
            for (int j = 0; j < blocksize; j++)
                outputs[i][j] = 0;
        }

        a.processReplacing(inputs, outputs, blocksize);

        VST.dispose(a);
    }
}
}
```

*EDIT*
The error it gives is:

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 

    at SoundPlayer.main(SoundPlayer.java:35)
```

Comment: You might want to narrow your question down a bit. "It doesn't work" is not a useful description.

Comment: What is this line? (almost at the end) `public static void main(String[] args); throws Exception {`

Comment: I got it from [http://jvst.sourceforge.net/] @MByD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I imported the JVST JAR into my build path and voila! The import org.boris.jvst.*; worked